# how to arrange blog posts by categories in next-sanity

Tags: next.js, bots, blogs, sanity

how to arrange blog post by categories in next-sanity.

[click to view what I meant to arrange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahLhv.png)

All of my blogs in one line like
category 1

category 1 blog, category 2 blog, category 3 blog

i want them like
category 1

category 1 blogs.

category 2

category 2blogs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group posts by category, you can do that in your query by using [joins](https://www.sanity.io/docs/query-cheat-sheet#e82ab8c0925b) and the special [references](https://www.sanity.io/docs/query-cheat-sheet#f62fbf6d7e14) variable:

```
*[_type == 'category'] {
  ...,
  "posts": *[_type == 'post' && references(^._id)]
}
```

Here we are querying the category documents first `*[_type == 'category']` then for each `category` projection we are querying for all `post` documents that *references* this category by `id`: `*[_type == 'post' && references(^._id)]`. The `^` parent operator refers the parent document, in this case the `category` document.

For more details you can check this [link](https://www.sanity.io/docs/how-queries-work#52023b22ca05) from the official docs.
I hope this helps